# Adding the sorted elements in list

Tags: python, sortedlist

I have a list ["Roll_Number","Marks in subjects"]:

```
list_1=[(1,22),(1,22),(2,29),(2,16),(3,56),(4,32),(4,12)]
```

I tried this code in python to get sum of all subjects for each roll_no :

```
 sub_sum = [0] * 4 #Roll No :4
 if i in range(0,len(list1)):
 if k in range(0,5):
    if (list1[i][0]==k):
       sub_sum[k] = list1[i][1] + sub_sum[k]
       i=i+1
    else:
        k=k+1
        break
```

Getting an infinite loop.
Expected Result : `1:44 , 2:45, 3:56 , 4:44`
Thanks in advance.

Comment: No you don't. Give us the actual code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that as follows:

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = [(1,22),(1,22),(2,29),(2,16),(3,56),(4,32),(4,12)]

b = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
for i,j in a:
    b[i] += j

>>> print b
{1:44, 2:45, 3:56, 4:44}
```

### DEMO

Comment: Use `d = defaultdict(lambda: 0)` and you won't need the `try-except`, or `b[i] = b.get(i, 0) + j` even.

Comment: @ErikAllik, I am a bit busy right now. Please feel free to edit my answer with your suggestions. Thank you very much.

Comment: `defaultdict(int)` works because `int() == 0`. Better than a lambda expression.

Comment: Thanks sshashank and Erik, can we further sort this final dictionary "b" by marks I mean the 2d element ?

Answer (score 1):

Since your list is sorted by first element already, you can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) for a relatively simple one-line solution:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby as gb
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> 
>>> l = [(1,22),(1,22),(2,29),(2,16),(3,56),(4,32),(4,12)]
>>> 
>>> {a: sum(t[1] for t in b) for a,b in gb(l, itemgetter(0))}
{1: 44, 2: 45, 3: 56, 4: 44}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using defaultdict

```
>>> list_1=[(1,22),(1,22),(2,29),(2,16),(3,56),(4,32),(4,12)]
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> res = defaultdict(int)
>>> for key, val in list_1:
...   res[key] += val
... 
>>> print res
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {1: 44, 2: 45, 3: 56, 4: 44})
>>> print dict(res)
{1: 44, 2: 45, 3: 56, 4: 44}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use the `groupby` from `itertools`

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> result = [(k, sum(r[1] for r in rows)) for k, rows in groupby(list_1, key=itemgetter(0))]
>>> result
[(1, 44), (2, 45), (3, 56), (4, 44)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most intuitive

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain, repeat
Counter(chain.from_iterable(repeat(x, y) for x, y in list_1))
Counter({3: 56, 2: 45, 1: 44, 4: 44})
```

Comment: This is a very wasteful approach. List multiplication is completely unnecessary here. Not to mention nobody will have a clue as to what you're trying to do just by looking at the code.

Comment: @arshajii, it's a lark

Comment: @arshajii, eliminated the list multiplication. As for the readability part granted it's not very readable - but that goes for your groupby solution as well