# IndexError: list index out of range but I have more than enough elements?! Python

Tags: python

```
def build_country_dict(lines):
    '''Return a dictionary in form of {country: count}, where country is
       the country code and count is the number of medals won by athletes
       from that country'''
    d = {}                                  #Start with an empty dictionary
    for i in range(1, len(lines)):          #For i ranging from 1 to the length of lines
        line_list = lines[i].split(',')     #  Split lines[i] into a list - split on comma
        country = line_list[6]              #  Get the country
        if country not in d:                #  If the country is not in the dictionary
            d[country] = 0                  #    Add it with count of 0
        d[country] = d[country] + 1         #  Add one to the country count
    return d                                #Return the dictionary
```

The error `IndexError: list index out of range` is referring to `line_list[6]` however the list I am using has 11 elements in it so I have no idea how to correct this.

The original file is a cvs file, so using excel I checked through the whole thing and every single line should turn into a list containing 11 elements. However the file is too large for me to print all the lists.

I did try with a smaller portion
print(line_list[6])
and it printed just fine.

Comment: Have you tried printing `line_list` on each iteration, to see if it does indeed have enough elements before the error occurs?  Maybe you have one oddball line snuck in there, or even a blank line, something like that.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/23281984/346478 for a hint, how to use defaultdict (and couple of alternative solutions) for your task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lines[i]` doesn't seem to have sufficient data to split by '**,**'.

Try this code instead of `country = line_list[6]`

```
country = line_list[6] if len(line_list) > 6 else 'unknown'
```

Alternatively,

```
try:
    country = line_list[6]
except IndexError:
    continue
```

This fits the situation more.

Comment: This line replacement works. Thank you.
It end up saying I have one unknown, so I went through the 2000 something lines again but I still couldn't find it.

Comment: And why is the index started at `1`. `index` of Python is started at `0` likely to `c` and so on.